# Mysql recursive substracting and multiplying values

Tags: mysql, join, recursion, sum

Couldn't really explain my problem with words, but with an example I can show it clearly:

I have a table like this:

```
id    num   val
0     3     10
1     5     12
2     7     12
3     11    15
```

And I want to go through all the rows, and calculate the increase of the "num", and multiply that difference with the "val" value. And when I calculated all of these, I want to add these results together.

This is the mathematical equation, that I want to run on the table:

```
Result = (3-0)*10 + (5-3)*12 + (7-5)*12 + (11-7)*15
138 = Result
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with mysql variables, but you will still get one record for each entry.

```
select
      @lastTotal := @lastTotal + ( (yt.num - @lastNum) * yt.val ) thisLineTotal,
      @lastNum := yt.num as saveForNextRow,
      yt.id
   from
      yourTable yt,
      ( select @lastTotal := 0,
               @lastNum := 0 ) sqlvars
   order by
      id
```

This SHOULD give you what you want to confirm the calculations to each record basis.

Now, to get the one record and one column result, you can wrap it such as

```
select
      pq.thisLineTotal
   from
      (above entire query ) as pq
   order by 
      pq.id DESC
   limit 1
```

Comment: I was thinking:

select 
sum((a.num - ifnull(b.num, 0)) * a.val) as result
from tt a
left join tt b on b.id = (a.id - 1);

However this assumes id always increments by one.  I like the trick of variables in a join.

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but I've realized that I've left out a crucial part of my problem from the question, could you please look at my modified question here? : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726266/mysql-recursive-substracting-and-multiplying-grouped-values)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the total. Make sure to order in the order you wish - I have ordered by id

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SET @prevval:=0;

select max(rt) as total FROM (
SELECT
   q.val,
   q.num,
   (@runtot := @runtot + (q.num- @prevval) * q.val) AS rt,
   (@prevval := q.num) AS pv
FROM thetable q
ORDER by ID) tot
```

If you want to see the details of the calculation, leave out the outer select as so:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SET @prevval:=0;

SELECT
   q.val,
   q.num,
   (@runtot := @runtot + (q.num- @prevval) * q.val) AS rt,
   (@prevval := q.num) AS pv
FROM thetable q
ORDER by ID
```

If it is possible to have negative numbers for your column values, using max(rt) won't work for the total. You should then use:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SET @prevval:=0;

select @runtot as total FROM (
SELECT
   q.val,
   q.num,
   (@runtot := @runtot + (q.num- @prevval) * q.val) AS rt,
   (@prevval := q.num) AS pv
    FROM thetable q
ORDER by ID) tot LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IDs are consecutive as your sample data suggests, just join the table to itself:

```
select sum((t1.num-ifnull(t2.num,0))*t1.val) YourValue
from YourTable t1
  left join YourTable t2
    on t2.id = t1.id - 1;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40b9f/12