# Mysql recursive substracting and multiplying grouped values

Tags: mysql, join, recursion, sum

Couldn't really explain my problem with words, but with an example I can show it clearly:

I have a table like this:

```
id    num   val  flag
0     3     10   1
1     5     12   2
2     7     12   1
3     11    15   2
```

And I want to go through all the rows, and calculate the increase of the "num", and multiply that difference with the "val" value. And when I calculated all of these, I want to add these results together, but grouped based on the "flag" values.

This is the mathematical equation, that I want to run on the table:

```
Result_1 = (3-0)*10 + (7-3)*12
Result_2 = (5-0)*12 + (11-5)*15

78  = Result_1
150 = Result_2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  Unfortunately `MYSQL` doesn't support `recursive queries`, so you'll need to be a little creative here.  Something like this could work:

```
select flag,
  sum(calc)
from (
  select flag, 
    (num-if(@prevflag=flag,@prevnum,0))*val calc,
    @prevnum:=num prevnum,
    @prevflag:=flag prevflag
  from yourtable 
    join (select @prevnum := 0, @prevflag := 0) t
  order by flag
  ) t
group by flag
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d3c6/1)